# Simple grouping example with aggregate framework in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So i apologize if this question exists, I can't find an answer that suits my needs, but I think it is quite simple, unfortunately I am still new to Mongo's non-basic features despite having dabbled with it off and on for the past 2 years.

**My Data:**
I have a collection which is a pretty straightforward set of documents, each representing a line item of inventory for microchips, the chips all have part numbers, stock codes, datecodes and quantites

(datecodes indicating when the item was produced: 0611 would usually mean June 2011 for those unfamiliar.)

The part number is the most important piece of data to an ed user running a search, however, a part number may show up multiple times in the set because it is the stock code (which represents PN + date code) which represents an individual line item. Unfortunately the external end user doesn't give a flying fudge about the stock code.

For this particular search I need to group all of the part numbers and return the total quantity for said part number - for this particular lookup I do not need the date codes.

So essentially, from  these three docs:

{pn:1234, qty:200, datecode:0611, stockcode:1}
{pn:1234, qty:300, datecode:0411, stockcode:2}
{pn:1254, qty:100, datecode:0601, stockcode:3}

I need my query to yield:

{pn:1234, qty:500}
{pn:1254, qty:100}

**My Problem:**
My problem is pretty simple, I can't seem to find an example that does such a simple group using the aggregate framework. Everything has more specific and complex (if only slightly) examples.

**My Code:**
The code I am trying is this:

```
db.collection.aggregate( { $group :
                         { _id : "$pn",
                           total_qty : { $sum : "$qty" } } },
                       { $match : {qty : { $gte : 1 } } } )
```

Does this make sense?

Thanks in advance to anyone.

Comment: MongoDb offers free online courses at education.mongodb.com your should definitely check that out. I have just completed one myself.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look. I will be using it more and more going forward.

Answer (score 2):

When the aggregation pipeline gets to your `$match`, the docs will have fields of `_id` and `total_qty`, but your match is on `qty` which no longer exists.  So change that to `total_qty` instead:

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $group : { _id : "$pn", total_qty : { $sum : "$qty" } } },
    { $match : {total_qty : { $gte : 1 } } }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

aggregation is a pipeline, you should pass an array of stages to it, in this case our first stage is matching and our second stage is grouping, so we should format it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {$match: ... }, {$group: ... }])
```